# FutureBuilder not refreshing with new data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TabFolder. In my tabs, I have a ListView with a number of buttons. The buttons are created by reference to items in a JSON file, which means I have to use a Future to get the JSON and a FutureBuilder to build my list. All of this is working fine.

Now, When I long press an item in this list, I pop up an Alert requesting user to confirm or cancel the operation. The operation is to delete. When confirmed, the delete then removes the button item from the JSON file. This works just fine.

I am now trying to rebuild the list, with the item removed, but no matter what I have tried, it just stays there, until I move to another tab and back again (which I have to repeat twice).

How do I get my FutureBuilder to refresh the call to the JSON. I have tried to do another call to get my Future (JSON) in the return from the alert, I have tried in my FutureBuilder, I have tried in the onLongPress, I have tried putting setState in many places...

This async is frustrating, when you know it should work (and will work if I did not have to use async and Futures).
Anyway, here is my code for my FutureBuilder.

```
  Widget buildInProgress(List<Widget> inProgressList) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<InProgressList>(
        future: futureInProgressList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            inProgressList.clear();
            snapshot.data!.Forms!.forEach((InProgressItems formItem) {
              inProgressList.add(
                Container(
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        RichText(text: TextSpan(
                            text: formItem.formName! + "\n",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(
                                text: formItem.displayDetail!,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 11.0,),
                              ),
                            ]
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      getFormSendData(context, formItem);
                    },
                    onLongPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _popupDeleteQuestion(context, formItem);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[400]!)),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
            return
              ListView(
                children: inProgressList,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          // By default, show a loading spinner
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have set up my TabController with a listener to handle the Tab Selection...

```
  _handleTabSelection() {

    switch(_tabController!.index) {
      case 0:
        setState(() {

        });
        break;
      case 1:
        setState(() {
          futureFormList = fetchForms();
        });
        break;
      case 2:
        setState(() {
          futureInProgressList = showInProgressOrSubmitted("InProgress.json");
        });
        break;
      case 3:
        setState(() {
          futureSubmittedList = showInProgressOrSubmitted("Submitted.json");
        });
        break;
    }

  }
```

The listener hits, and the BuildInProgress hits, but the page does not refresh with the new data.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

```
  void _popupDeleteQuestion(BuildContext context, InProgressOrSubmittedItems formItem) async {

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context)
        {
          return AlertDialog(
            title:Text("DELETE FORM"),
            content: StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (context, setState) {

                  return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      Text("Warning: This will delete all the data contained in this form.")

                    ],
                  );
                }),

            actions: <Widget>[
              new TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState((){

                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                //Color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child:  Text('Cancel'),
              ),
              new TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  _deleteForm(formItem);
                  setState((){
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  });

                },
                child:  Text('Accept'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });

  }

  void _deleteForm(InProgressOrSubmittedItems formItem) async {
    HandleFile file = new HandleFile();

    file.deleteFile("${formItem.documentId}*");

    String detailFile = await file.readFile("InProgress.json");

    Map<String, dynamic> formData = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    if (detailFile != "")
    {
      formData = jsonDecode(detailFile);
    }

    List<dynamic> ipforms = [];

    if (formData.isNotEmpty)
    {
      ipforms = formData["FileList"];
    }

    List<dynamic> formDetail = [];
    try {
      formDetail = ipforms.where((element) => element["documentId"] !=
          formItem.documentId).toList();
    }
    catch (e) {

    }

    formData["FileList"] = formDetail;

    file.writeFile("InProgress.json", json.encode(formData));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of trying to figure this out, I now have it working. With some help from @John Joe, and more googling, I have totally changed the method. Instead of looping through and adding items to a List, I now do it directly with a ListView.builder. I think the ListView.builder was the key, combined with the suggestions by John.

```
  Widget buildInProgressList() {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<InProgressOrSubmittedList>(
          future: futureInProgressList,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.pForms!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    InProgressOrSubmittedItems formItem = snapshot.data!
                        .pForms![index];
                    return Container(
                      child: TextButton(
                        child: Row(

                          children: [
                            RichText(text: TextSpan(
                                text: formItem.formName! + "\n",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                                children: <TextSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: formItem.displayDetail!,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 11.0,),

                                  ),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "\nLast Updated: ${formatDate(
                                        formItem.lastUpdated!)}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 11.0,),

                                  ),
                                ]
                            )),
                          ],
                        ),

                        onPressed: () async {
                          await getFormSendData(context, formItem).then((
                              onValue) {
                            setState(() {});
                            futureInProgressList =
                                showInProgressOrSubmitted("InProgress.json");
                          });
                        },
                        onLongPress: () async {
                          await _popupDeleteQuestion(context, formItem).then((
                              onValue) {
                            setState(() {});
                            futureInProgressList =
                                showInProgressOrSubmitted("InProgress.json");
                          });
                          //futureInProgressList = showInProgressOrSubmitted("InProgress.json");

                        },

                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        //color: Colors.purple[400],
                        border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[400]!)),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              );
            }
            else
              {
                return Container();
              }
          }
      ),
    );
  }
```

I also had to make some changes to how my deletes were handled. In the onPressed of the Accept button on my AlertDialog I have also done similar to the solution that John mentioned.

```
onPressed: () async {
   await _deleteForm(formItem).then((value) {
       Navigator.of(context).pop();
       setState(() {});
       futureInProgressList = showInProgressOrSubmitted("InProgress.json");
   });
},
```

I had to make my _deleteForm function a Future so that I could get the ".then".

Hope this helps others that have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `setState` after delete method.If your delete method return `Future`, add `await` in front of the method.

```
 _popupDeleteQuestion(context, formItem);
 setState(() {});
```

**Edit**

In `_popupDeleteQuestion` method, you don't really need to add `setState`. Add `await` infront.

```
onPressed: () async {
      await _deleteForm(formItem);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
```

After `_popupDeleteQuestion` method called, call `setState` to rebuild.

```
 _popupDeleteQuestion(context, formItem).then((onValue){
      setState(() {});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have edited and put an await so now it looks await _popupDeleteQuestion(context, formItem); however, I have a red mark that says it can only be put in an async function. If I make my buildInProgress async, it then tells me that Widget needs to be a Future.

Comment: Let me clarify that... my _popupDeleteQuestion returns a void, but it is an async method. The tab is still showing the old data having changed my onLongPress (and I have also changed my _handleTabSelection. It still doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Delete code added. The onLongPress is to pop up an alert dialog, and when Accept is clicked, it then calls the delete.

Comment: Thank you for continuing with this. To make these work (I had red lines on both _deleteForm and _popupDeleteQuestion), I had to add "Future" to both the _popupDeleteQuestion and the _deleteForm functions. It still didn't work. I have then made onLongPress async and await _popupDeleteQuestion, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: When I first start the app, my tabfolder calls the showInProgressOrSubmitted. When I click the tab, it calls again. When I long press on row, it calls again. When I click Accept on the delete, it calls _deleteForm. It does not re-call showInProgressOrSubmitted. When I change tab (and back again), it calls showInProgressOrSubmitted twice, but there is no update to the screen to show it has been removed. (I am still a newby at Flutter)

Comment: "_When I change tab (and back again), it calls showInProgressOrSubmitted twice, but there is no update to the screen to show it has been removed._"  Maybe data not getting removed? Have you checked is the data still there?

Comment: I store the listed items in a JSON file. I open the JSON file and can see that the items have been removed from it. The showInProgressOrSubmitted is actually a future to read the JSON file to display on the page. In my further research, I found https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62019 which suggests that the ListView doesn't work properly with a FutureBuilder. (My Listview is set up inside a DefaultTabController widget. the TabBarView calls the buildInPrgress (and other) widgets (none of the widgets being refreshed properly). I even tried a didUpdateWidget with no luck.

Comment: I have re-written how the ListView is built, using ListView.builder instead and I have it mostly working now. Some of it is using what you suggested above (the .then(value) call). I will continue as I am for the moment, to fix the last few niggles and I will post as a solution how I got it to work.